# new object in function always return same object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I wrote a function to generate mock object like following

```
export function createOrderMock(): Order {
  return new Order(props);
}
```

and I imported and used that in test code

```
import { createOrderMock } from './mocks/order.mock';

describe('test1', () => {
  it('test1', () => {
      const order: Order = createOrderMock();
  })
})


describe('test2', () => {
  it('test2', () => {
      const order2: Order = createOrderMock();
  })
})
```

but `order` and `order2` always same object. so if order is changed in test1, order2 is changed as well.

What is my mistake?

Comment: "order and order2 always same object". How do you detecting that thing?

Comment: there was no reason to fail in test2, but it kept failing. so i tried debugging order2 was changed from test2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `props`?

```js
export function createOrderMock(): Order {
  return new Order(props);
}
```

While you create a new `Order` object each time you call `createOrderMock()`, all of them will be created with the same `props`.

I suspect that this is why changing properties on `order` in `test1` affects the `order2` object created in `test2`.

If `props` is a plain JavaScript object, you can try with:

```js
export function createOrderMock(): Order {
  return new Order({ ...props });. // Will use a shallow copy of props
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `jest.clearAllMocks();` before or after each test.

This will cleanup mocks that you made, making tests and mock object independent from each other